# php array strip_tags and unset

Tags: php, var, unset, strip-tags

hello everybody i have a question regarding strip_tags function.
i have an html document like that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>er</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and this php script

```
<?php
$file = "ht.html";
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
$data = fread($fp, filesize($file));
fclose($fp);
$output = str_replace("\t|\t", "|", $data);
$outputline = explode("\n", $output);
$lexeisline=count($outputline);

for ($i = 0; $i < $lexeisline; $i++){
    $outputline[$i]=strip_tags($outputline[$i]);
      if (empty($outputline[$i])){
          unset($outputline[$i]);
}
}
$outputline = array_values($outputline);
$lexeisline=count($outputline);
echo "<p>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $lexeisline; $i++){
echo ($outputline[$i])."<br />";
}
echo "</p>";
?>
```

the problem is that it does not unset the empty vars(which are returned from the strip_tags) and echos something like this. does the following means that it echos empty strings?
any opinion or help will be very appreciated. Thanx in advance

```
<p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />Untitled Document
<br />
<br />
<br />er
<br />
<br /></p>
```

@phpmeh

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => Untitled Document
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => er
        [8] => 
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems incredibly baroque for what you are doing. Does the following code do what you need?

```
$lines = file('ht.html');
$lines = array_map('strip_tags', $lines);
$lines = array_map('trim', $lines);
$lines = array_filter($lines);

echo "<p>\n", implode("<br />\n", $lines), "\n</p>";
```

Comment: is by far the greatest solution

Comment: Note that it's still not a good idea to apply `strip_tags` on a line-by-line basis, because you could have a tag that spans multiple lines.  It's better to apply `strip_tags` to the entire string once, then split into lines with `explode`. But you're not entirely clear on what your want your code to do, and this code will do the same thing your code does.

Answer (score 2):

You're just counting through and echoing for each.  If you want to skip empty, do something like this in your loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $lexeisline; $i++){
if(!empty($outputline[$i]) echo ($outputline[$i])."<br />";
}
```

Hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: Yes you did understund!!!! well this is almost the same with what i have done(simplified thow) , and it has the same results with mine.In my script i want to unset the empty vars, and its not working.In your script you echo the vars that are not empty but still does not work.

Comment: @Calvin: You need to have empty check for something, as you have it now you are just doing `(!empty)`, try `(!empty(outputline[$i]))`.

Comment: @teo6389: You tried `if (!empty(outputline[$i])) echo ($outputline[$i])."<br />";` and it still didn't work?

Comment: add a echo '<pre>'; print_r($outputline); echo '</pre>';  Post it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably wrong... but...

When you explode these lines, I'm pretty sure they have an implicit /n that is going to mean they're never empty.  An alternative, though it is a little slower, would be:

```
 strlen( $outline[$i] ) > 0
```

Comment: i've tried that and i have the same results with mine. php will drive us crazy...

Comment: Well ya, because if there is an implice /n, then it needs to be strlen > 2